# Automatically instrumenting Java application using AWS X-Ray

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I am trying to achieve automatic instrumentation of all calls made by AWS SDKs for Java using X-Ray.

> The X-Ray SDK for Java automatically instruments all AWS SDK clients when you include the AWS SDK Instrumentor submodule in your build dependencies.
>   ([from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/scorekeep-sdkclients.html))

I have added these to my POM
`aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core`
`aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk`
`aws-xray-recorder-sdk-spring`
`aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor`

and am using e.g. `aws-java-sdk-ssm` and `aws-java-sdk-sqs`.

I expected to only have to add the X-Ray packages to my POM and provide adequate IAM policies.
However, when I start my application I get exceptions such as these:

`com.amazonaws.xray.exceptions.SegmentNotFoundException: Failed to begin subsegment named 'AWSSimpleSystemsManagement': segment cannot be found.`

I tried wrapping the SSM call in a manual segment and so that worked but then immediately the next call from another AWS SDK throws a similar exception.

How do I achieve the automatic instrumentation mentioned in the documentation? Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you make AWS SDK calls in your application. If you have added X-Ray servlet to your spring application per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-filters.html then each time your application receives a request, the X-Ray servlet filter will open a segment and store it in the thread serving that request. Any AWS SDK calls you make as part of that request/response cycle will pick up that segment as the parent.

The error you got means the the X-Ray instrumentor tries to record the AWS API call to a subsegment but it cannot find a parent (which request this call belongs to).

Depending on your use case you might want to explicitly instrument certain AWS SDK clients and left others plain, if some of those clients are making calls in a background worker.